# Google Maps API: Map won't display in Modal

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps API with Angular 2. Everything was working fine until I put the map inside of a modal and now the map won't display. I did some searching and tried invoking the following code once my modal opens:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

This is giving me the following build error:

> Cannot find name 'map'.

How do I get around this error?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more code for this?  Your modal component/template perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting `*ngIf="latitude"` on the div surrounding my map so it wouldn't be shown until a value for latitude existed. This took care of my problem for me.